# loop through objects using Object.entries

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a comobox component to display tags from an API request. The component receives the tags as a prop in this format:

```
"tags": [ { "name": "Rejected" }, { "name": "Accepted" } ] }
```

I'm trying to get the value `name` and make it as `v-model`, to display the tags saved in DB and hold new tags if users need to update them. Here is the comobox code:

```html
 <v-container fluid>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="model"
    :items="items"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    hide-selected
    hint="Maximum of 5 tags"
    label="Add some tags"
    multiple
    persistent-hint
    small-chips
  >
    <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
            No results matching "<strong>{{ search }}</strong>". Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to create a new one
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </template>
  </v-combobox>
</v-container>
```

Props

```
props:{
  value:{
    required: true,
    type:Object
  }
}
```

computed

```
computed: {
  model() {
   return Object.entries(this.value.tags).forEach(([key,value]) => {
     return this.model = value
   })
  }
},
```

The issue when I try to get the value using `Object.entries` (something I want to use to iterate through the properties) is:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: A return statement inside a `forEach` has no effect. `tags` contains an array, so `Object.entries()` will have unexpected result. Regardless of all that, clearly, `this.value.tags` is `undefined` or `null`. Type this in the console and watch it work: `Object.entries({name: 'test', number: 42})
`

Comment: so how to forEach over undefined or null Type?

Comment: um...you can't. `forEach()` is a method of the Array object (and some other Array like objects) in JavaScript. That implies you much call it from a valid Array object. An empty object is still an object, so `[].forEach(console.log);` works, but doesn't do anything since there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: are you saying there is no solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Error

The `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error indicates that `this.value.tags` is not yet defined when computed. The computed prop runs at initialization *before* `value` is provided. One solution is to specify a default value in the prop declaration that contains an initial `tags`:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      default: () => ({ tags: [] })
    }
  }
}
```

#### Extracting values from `tags` array

If I understand correctly, you're trying to map the `name` values from `tags[]` into an array. You can do this with   [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    model() {
      // takes the `name` property from each object in `tags[]`
      return this.value.tags.map(({ name }) => name)
    }
  }
}
```

#### Binding to computed prop

I noticed you're binding the `model` computed prop in `<v-combobox v-model="model">`, but `v-model` requires a writable property, which `model` is not. You should see a console warning in development mode regarding this.

I think `model` really should be `items` here. The user's selected value would be stored in `v-model`, so that should be some property declared in your component's `data()`:

```html
<template>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="selectedItems"
    :items="model"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItems: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    model() { /* ... */ }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Combobox in Vuetify]